# How to fetch data from table by using range of date and wild card in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to search data based on Range of date and matching records in the MS database, I am using below sql query

```
select * 
from table_name
where column_name1 between 'from date' and 'to date'
  and column_name2 like '%-R'
```

It is not working, could you please some one explain why it's not working and let me know is their any other way.

Comment: Please don't say _It is not working_.  That is extremely vague and unhelpful in diagnosing an issue. Also, provide the error message if there is one or describe why you feel it is not working. Lastly, tell us about how to tried to resolve this issue and why it still doesn't work.

Comment: what is the search pattern that you are looking for and what is the data type of column_name1? are you sure you are using the correct date format?

Comment: Your where predicate is pretty suspect. I doubt you are looking for strings between two values.

Comment: If you can show your table schema and sample data and expected output, that would help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what formatting I use to search between 2 dates:

```
-- try not to use * in your select.  Pick the columns you actually need.

Select * from table_name 
where column_name1 between '2016/12/25' and '2016/12/27'
and column_name2 like '%-R'
```

I'm not actually sure what is not working exactly so I can't tell you how to fix it, only give you an example to go by.  The dates you put in will need to be formatted to fit the date column in your table.

Comment: Using dates in either `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy` format is asking for problems.  Better to use something less ambiguous like `yyyy/MM/dd`

Comment: Dave.  I agree and I usually do the way you suggested.  I also stated that it depends on the formatting of his column, but I'll change my code to reflect best practice.